# A Vector space problem

Tags: linear-algebra

If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are vector subspaces of a vector space $V$ then $W_1+W_2$ is a vector subspace of $V$. I have two questions:

> (i) What is $W_1+W_2$ if $W_1=W_2$?
>
> (ii) What is $W_1+W_2$ if $W_1$ is a subset of $W_2$?

My answer: (i) $W_1$ or $W_2;\;$ (ii) $W_2$.

Is it correct?

Comment: It is quite correct.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Your answers are correct: why don't you write an appropriate answer of your question (using LaTex) including all the details?